# OpenMP Array Conversion

Tags: arrays, openmp, nested-loops

I need to perform the array operation within the nested loop. The function `dosomething()` requires it in this fashion. How can I do this correctly?

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
#pragma omp for ordered
for (int i = 1; i < iter; i++)
{

       #pragma omp ordered
        for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++)
        {
            info2[j][0] = info[j];
        }

        dosomething(info2);
}
}
```

This is my problem: without the ordered directives, the array `info2` is incorrect every time. However, using the ordered directives takes a fair amount more time than with everything in serial. What is a better way of doing this?

Comment: This sounds like a race condition. Making `info2` `private` (you can call it `info3`) should take care of it. You may need to perform some sort of reduction after the parallel region to get the right `info2` from all those `info3`.

Comment: By the way why can't you do `info2[0:rows-1][0] = info[0:rows-1];` (I am not sure about the correct C syntax, I use Fortran) avoiding the loop completely? Modern CPUs do such operations in parallel automatically using their hardware support and it will probably be faster than using OpenMP.

Comment: @PetrH no, C does not have that.

Comment: @PetrH essentially something like this?
      #pragma omp parallel
      {
         #pragma omp for private(info3)
        for (int i = 1; i < iter; i++)
             {
                for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++)
                      {
                          info3[j][0] = info[j];
                       }
         info2 += info3
        dosomething(info2);
       }
      }

Comment: How about only parallelizing the inner loop over `j`? What size is rows? In any case reading `info2[j][0]` is going to be terribly unfriendly.

Comment: @aeronautics13 When looking at your code again it seems to me that actually making `info2` `private` (the way you did with `info3` above) would be enough (no "reduction" needed). That may depend on your code (in particular on what exactly `dosomething()` does and possibly on what happens before the `j` loop).

Comment: @VladimirF Ah, OK, this explains that. One possibility could then be to write that part in Fortran and call from C. I am guessing for this to be worth it the problem would have to be big and the performance of this section of the code crucial.

Comment: @aeronautics13 One more comment `j` should of course be `private` too (saying just in case). Also you are aware of C's row major, aren't you? It would be faster to do `info2[0][j]` if the structure of your problem allows to swap the indices easily.

Comment: `j` is private automatically as it is declared inside. I still don't get what dosomething is doing, why info2 has only the [0]?

Comment: @Zboson "rows" is actually quite large (in the 100 thousands). I believe parallelizing the inner loop is far less efficient than doing so for the outer loop.

Comment: @PetrH unfortunately, this is the way I have to do it. The function can't be changed to allow anything different. Overall, I am performing this very expensive operation because I'm using a matrix library. As such, `info` is in this library's vector form while the function requires the array `info2.` OpenMP seems to be filling `info2` in any order it pleases without the `ordered.` Using private on `info` throws a "not declared" error; using `firstprivate` doesn't seem to help.